# Radio Button Group Initialization Failure

Tags: php, html

**The Code Snippet :** Consider the code snippet ( https://jsfiddle.net/Zikaynam/sgha2fkg ) :

```
<?php
    $gender = "";
?>

<label>Gender<span>*</span></label>

<div>
    <div id="gender" data-toggle="buttons radio">

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked=<?php ( $gender=="M" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>/>&nbsp; Male &nbsp;
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" checked=<?php ( $gender=="F" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>/> Female
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="L" checked=<?php ( $gender=="L" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>/> LGBT
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Intention :** The intention of the code snippet is to initialize a global variable and use the said global variable to determine which radio button is initially "checked" or if all radio buttons are initially "unchecked".

**The Failure :** As it is shown in the given link I initialized the global variable with "" intending to initially set the radio buttons as "unchecked" but it turns out that one of the radio buttons was "checked".  I am new to web development so I may have missed something or messed something up, so can anyone show me what was wrong with my code snippet and why didn't it act as I intended it to?  thank you for the advice.

Comment: You are setting a variable to an empty string - and then you do a couple of tests, to see whether it has one of several values that are not an empty string ... how is that supposed to make _any_ sense?

Comment: then how come even if I initialized $gender as "M" it still didn't work? shouldn't the empty string not be a factor since I am testing the value and if the test failed the button shouldn't the radio button be unchecked?

Comment: That’s because `checked` is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) – its mere presence means it is considered as set, no matter what the value is. You have to not have `checked=` in there for radio buttons that are supposed to be unchecked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You never `echo` anything after testing the value of `$gender`, so the source code of your web page will always contain (whatever the value of `$gender` is):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked=/>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" checked=/>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="L" checked=/>
```

You can see that the HTML code is invalid: either the `=` character shouldn't be there, or it should be `checked="checked"`.
Your web browser is very kind, and does its best to display web pages that contain errors. In this case, it will probably ignore the `=` character, and see that all radio buttons are checked. But since only one radio button in a group may be checked, it will display one of them as checked.

**Advice**: when generating a web page with a server-side language like PHP, if you don't get what you expect and you don't understand what's wrong, you should check the source code in your browser. It often helps to spot where the problem is.

Fixed version:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <?php echo ( $gender=="M" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <?php echo ( $gender=="F" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="L" <?php echo ( $gender=="L" ) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```

See https://eval.in/613115 for the entire code.

Comment: hmmm if your point being that the $gender should not be initialized as blank, then why didn't it work even if I initialized $gender as "M"?

Answer (score 0):

I am withdrawing my question...finally found the problem..thank you for being so kind as to downpoint my question without even clarifying what the problem was and how do I resolve it....at least you left me 1 point which is really a booster for a newbie at web development..thanks anyway

Comment: I don't quite understand the down voting before they communicate anything.